# OrderByDescending does not sort List<string> properly

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

**UPDATE:**

Had to assign return Linq list to the variable 'columnData':

```
columnData = columnData.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

I'm having trouble using OrderByDescending to sort a simple string list. If I use .Sort() and then .Reverse() it works properly since I've read that .Sort() sorts naturally but the practice of using .Reverse() for descending order is bad practice in production code. So I'm doing it like this:

```
if(sortOrder == 1)
        {
            columnData.OrderBy(s => s);
        }
        else
        {
            columnData.OrderByDescending(s => s);
        }
```

But what I get after acending or descending is this:

[image]

But if I use Sort() and Reverse(), it sorts properly.

What is wrong with Linq sorting?

Comment: what type of columnData object is ?

Comment: @Disappointed updated my questions. Its a string list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrderBy does not change the value of the list. It returns a new ordered collection so what you have to do is:

```
    if(sortOrder == 1)
    {
        columnData = columnData.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        columnData = columnData.OrderByDescending(s => s).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t use the returned value of `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()`.
As stated in [LINQ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2), the methods returns a `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>`.