# C# Linq Sort by descending order vs SortBy order List returns the same ascending order?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Im simply trying to order my list from highest value int to lowest value int, descending.

```
list[0] = 24;
list[1] = 18;
list[2] = 12; // Correct order that I want.
```

Somehow using Linq.SortBy and Linq.SortByDescending returns the same ascending list though.

Heres my implementation:

```
            Dictionary<GunSO, int> gunsDictionary = shipControl.shipWrapper.cargo.GetEquippedGunsDictionary();
        
        List<KeyValuePair<GunSO, int>> sortedList = new List<KeyValuePair<GunSO, int>>();

        sortedList = gunsDictionary.ToList();
        sortedList.Sort(
            delegate (KeyValuePair<GunSO, int> pair1,
            KeyValuePair<GunSO, int> pair2)
                {
                    return pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value);
                }
        );

        sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Caliber);


        int b = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<GunSO, int> pair in sortedList)
        {
            print("pair[" + b + "].Key.Caliber = " + pair.Key.Caliber);
            b++;
        }
```

In this case I want to sort the list by Key.Caliber

The console returns the following when using Descending and SortBy:

```
pair[0].Key.Caliber = 12
pair[1].Key.Caliber = 18
pair[2].Key.Caliber = 24
```

Thats the exact wrong order(ascending).

Maybe it has something to do with the `delegate` above that, which is an answer I copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) SO answer, but dont really understand completely.

Thank you.

EDIT: Thank you commenter, I tried your suggestion using:

```
 sortedList = (List<KeyValuePair<GunSO, int>>)sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Caliber);
```

But now I get the following error:

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Thank agains.

Comment: `OrderByDescending()` returns a **new list**.  It doesn't sort the list in place.  So you would have to do `sortedList = sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Caliber).ToList();` See [OrderByDescending does not sort List<string> properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54249653), which looks to be a duplicate.  But why you are sorting `sortedList` twice?  The second sort will overwrite the sort order of the first.

Comment: Without the Cast, I got another error saying I need an explicit Cast...

Comment: You need to call `ToList()` just like you did when you called `gunsDictionary.ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

`sortedList.OrderByDescending` will not modify the order in `sortedList`, it will return a LINQ query. If you want to execute it and create a new list you have to use:

```
sortedList = OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Caliber).ToList();
```

Comment: Wow you guys did it again! In record time, this time!